# Can you change the default command line instruction of GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am hosting my own GitLab Server at my company and I want to change the command line instructions, which show up when you create a new project.

Is this even possible?

PS: I am familiar with the "New project page".

Comment: What do you want to change there? And why?

Comment: @MatthiasLohr I want to create a little manual for all useres. (Create gitignore, change some git commands)

Comment: You cannot customise this message unless you edit Gitlab's code yourself. Why not creating a project with this kind of docs and inform the users to read the guide?